# script generated input not formatting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

Just started working with javascript and have struggled to find a solution to formatting an input.

I have a form with inputs generated by a calculation script. When I manually enter numbers they are formatted to 2 decimal places using JQuery. However when the numbers are generated by the script the formatting does not work. I get numbers to 14 decimal places.

I have read something about the event not being triggered. Is this happening here ? any help greatfully received.

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
// apply the two-digits behaviour to elements with 'two-digits' as their class
$( function() {
    $('.two-digits').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().indexOf('.')!=-1){         
            if($(this).val().split(".")[1].length > 2){                
                if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
            }  
         }            
         return this; //for chaining
    });
});
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function cmConverter(){
document.converter.inchwidth.value = document.converter.cmwidth.value / 2.54

document.converter.inchdrop.value = document.converter.cmdrop.value  / 2.54 
}

//-->
</script>
```

My form html

```
Width cm: <input type="text" name="cmwidth" onChange="cmConverter()" ><br /> 

  Width Inch: <input type="text" name="inchwidth" id="a" class="two-digits"><br />

Drop cm: <input type="text" name="cmdrop" onChange="cmConverter()" ><br />

 Drop Inch: <input type="text" name="inchdrop"  id="d" class="two-digits"><br />
```

Comment: could the `/2.54` be causing this?

Comment: What do you mean by numbers generated by the script?

Comment: Hi Zee Tee, the /2.54 is not the problem. I have another input field that is filled automatically by another script. This has the same problem. The calculated answer is correct but just to 14 decimal places.

Comment: Hi Kinnza, When I say the numbers generated by the script. What I mean is that the user enters a sizes into the "cm" field. Then when they click on the next field. The function cmConverter() script converts this size into inches and adds this result into the inches field. The only problem is that the result is to 14 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this rounding to 2 decimal spaces problem. I ditched the jquery "two-digits" code and replaced it using Math.round(*100)/100